# SSRS: x-Axis display less characters

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to display less characters in the x-axis of my diagramm. How can I do this.
The x-axis now is too large:

[image]

I would like to display the characters like this here:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ofc you can.
For example you can use Expression if you want in Category group settings:

[image]

In properties chose Label Expression (fx button):

[image]

And create your expression, for example following showing 20 left chars + ... if lenght of string is more than 20:

```
=IIF(Len(Fields!groupX.Value) > 20,Left(Fields!groupX.Value,20) + "...",Fields!groupX.Value)
```

Where 20 is limit number of chars showed up in your chart...